# populate select dropdown with keys from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following json-array available:

```
{
    "Particulier": {
        "Weekend": {
            "2015": {
                "04": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "24-04-2015",
                        "endDate": "27-04-2015",
                        "price": 1111
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "15-04-2015",
                        "endDate": "22-04-2015",
                        "price": 9999
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "17-04-2015",
                        "endDate": "24-04-2015",
                        "price": 0
                    }
                ],
                "05": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "01-05-2015",
                        "endDate": "04-05-2015",
                        "price": 2222
                    }
                ]
            },
            "2016": {
                "05": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "08-05-2016",
                        "endDate": "15-05-2016",
                        "price": 5555
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "15-05-2016",
                        "endDate": "22-05-2016",
                        "price": 6666
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "13-05-2016",
                        "endDate": "20-05-2016",
                        "price": 11111
                    }
                ],
                "04": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "24-04-2016",
                        "endDate": "27-04-2016",
                        "price": 1111
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "15-04-2016",
                        "endDate": "22-04-2016",
                        "price": 9999
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "17-04-2016",
                        "endDate": "24-04-2016",
                        "price": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Midweek": {
            "2015": {
                "04": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "20-04-2015",
                        "endDate": "24-04-2015",
                        "price": 3333
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "27-04-2015",
                        "endDate": "01-05-2015",
                        "price": 4444
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Clienten en patienten": {
        "Weekend": {
            "2016": {
                "01": [
                    {
                        "startDate": "08-01-2016",
                        "endDate": "11-01-2016",
                        "price": 7777
                    },
                    {
                        "startDate": "09-01-2016",
                        "endDate": "16-01-2016",
                        "price": 8888
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve all the keys on the same level so they can be used by jQuery to populate a select dropdown.

With on the same level I mean : 'Particulier' & 'Clienten en patienten' and 'Weekend' & 'Midweek' & 'Week' and so on..

If any information is required please ask, new to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you consider a "key" in this data?

Comment: Yes it is. You just need to iterate and collect. Do you know how to iterate over the properties of an object?

Comment: Can you post the enitre completed json, Because the one you post up is not a valid json

Comment: @user1477388 The ones I mentioned:  'Particulier' & 'Clienten en patienten' and 'Weekend' & 'Midweek' & 'Week' and so on..

Comment: @FelixKling Not really..

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json then.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the link! Good reading material!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wvLapox/

```
$.each( d, function( key1, value1 ) {
    console.log(value1);
    $.each( value1, function( key2, value2 ) {
       $('#put').append( $('<div></div>').html(key2) );
    });
});
```

Output:

```
Weekend 
Midweek
```

### Edit:

Based on your comment, looks like you only want the first level:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wvLapox/2/

```
$.each( d, function( key1, value1 ) {
    $('#put').append( $('<div></div>').html(key1) );
});
```

Output:

```
Particulier
Clienten en patienten
```

Comment: I wanted it on all levels, your answer was really helpfull! Thanks!

Comment: If you want it on all levels, then you should use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code:  `<select id="DLState">`

**JS Part:**

```
    var listItems= "";
$.each( datajson, function( key1, value1 ) {

    $.each( value1, function( key2, value2 ) {


        listItems+= "<option value='" + key2 + "'>" + key2 + "</option>";

    });

});
$("#DLState").html(listItems);
```

Try something like this demo [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/antoKing/4uyc88v2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys(jsonObject) will also help you to get keys and to list.